# Drawing decision boundary of two multivariate gaussian in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I will borrow the image from the following stack overflow question to help me describing my problem:
[Drawing decision boundary of two multivariate gaussian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576761/drawing-decision-boundary-of-two-multivariate-gaussian)

[image]

I have 2 classes with 2D points, and what I am interested in is the decision boundary (or discriminant).

I have written the functions that return the result for the discriminant functions (a float value) that allowed me to classify the samples into those 2 patterns.

if a sample point is e.g., x_i = [x, y]
I can call the functions
and

if `g1(x,y) > g2(x,y)` it's class 1, and vice versa if

`g1(x,y) <= g2(x,y)` it's class 2

So the decision boundary should be at `g1(x,y) == g2(x,y)`

---

**EDIT:**

Hope that an example is helpful: 


1) Let's assume I take 1 sample `x = [1, 2]` from the dataset


2) Then I will call e.g.
   `g1(1,2)` --> returns `0.345`
   `g2(1,2)` --> returns `0.453`
   --> sample x belongs to class 2, since `g2(1,2) > g1(1,2)`


3) Now for the decision boundary, I have `g2(x,y) == g1(x,y)`,
    or
   `g1(x,y) - g2(x,y)` == 0

4) I generate a range of `x` values, e.g., `1,2,3,4,5`, and now I want to
   find the corresponding `y` values that yield `g1(x,y) - g2(x,y) == 0`

5) then I can use these `x,y` pairs to plot the decision boundary

---

In the StackOverflow post that I linked above, the suggestion would be to

> you can simply plot the contour line of f(x,y) := pdf1(x,y) >
>   pdf2(x,y). So you define function f to be 1 iff pdf1(x,y)>pdf2(x,y).
>   This way the only contour will be placed along the curve where
>   pdf1(x,y)==pdf2(x,y) which is the decision boundary (discriminant). If
>   you wish to define "nice" function you can do it simply by setting
>   f(x,y) = sgn( pdf1(x,y) - pdf2(x,y) ), and plotting its contour plot
>   will result in exact same discriminant.

But how would I do it in Python and matplotlib, I am really lost setting up the code to do that. I am grateful for any help!

EDIT:

A little bit more about the function `g()` itself:

```
def discr_func(x, y, cov_mat, mu_vec):
    """
    Calculates the value of the discriminant function for a dx1 dimensional
    sample given covariance matrix and mean vector.

    Keyword arguments:
        x_vec: A dx1 dimensional numpy array representing the sample.
        cov_mat: dxd numpy array of the covariance matrix.
        mu_vec: dx1 dimensional numpy array of the sample mean.

    Returns a float value as result of the discriminant function.

    """
    x_vec = np.array([[x],[y]])

    W_i = (-1/2) * np.linalg.inv(cov_mat)
    assert(W_i.shape[0] > 1 and W_i.shape[1] > 1), 'W_i must be a matrix'

    w_i = np.linalg.inv(cov_mat).dot(mu_vec)
    assert(w_i.shape[0] > 1 and w_i.shape[1] == 1), 'w_i must be a column vector'

    omega_i_p1 = (((-1/2) * (mu_vec).T).dot(np.linalg.inv(cov_mat))).dot(mu_vec)
    omega_i_p2 = (-1/2) * np.log(np.linalg.det(cov_mat))
    omega_i = omega_i_p1 - omega_i_p2
    assert(omega_i.shape == (1, 1)), 'omega_i must be a scalar'

    g = ((x_vec.T).dot(W_i)).dot(x_vec) + (w_i.T).dot(x_vec) + omega_i
    return float(g)
```

And when I execute it, it would return a float, e.g.,

`discr_func(1, 2, cov_mat=cov_est_1, mu_vec=mu_est_1)`
`-3.726426544537969`

if I didn't make a mistake, it should be this equation: [image]

Thank you a lot for the suggestion with the contour, however, I have problems implementing it:

```
import pylab as pl

X, Y = np.mgrid[-6:6:100j, -6:6:100j]
x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()

p = (discr_func(x, y, cov_mat=cov_est_1, mu_vec=mu_est_1) -\
     discr_func(x, y, cov_mat=cov_est_2, mu_vec=mu_est_2)).reshape(X.shape)

#pl.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1])
pl.contour(X, Y, p, levels=[0])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-28c1c8787237> in <module>()
      5 y = Y.ravel()
      6 
----> 7 p = (discr_func(x, y, cov_mat=cov_est_1, mu_vec=mu_est_1) -     discr_func(x, y, cov_mat=cov_est_2, mu_vec=mu_est_2)).reshape(X.shape)
      8 
      9 #pl.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1])

<ipython-input-184-fd2f8b7fad82> in discr_func(x, y, cov_mat, mu_vec)
     25     assert(omega_i.shape == (1, 1)), 'omega_i must be a scalar'
     26 
---> 27     g = ((x_vec.T).dot(W_i)).dot(x_vec) + (w_i.T).dot(x_vec) + omega_i
     28     return float(g)

ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

My feeling is that the passing of the `.ravel()` list doesn't work well with how I set up this function... any suggestions?

Comment: your discr_func function can't calculate all values on a grid by one call. So you need a for loop to call discr_func for every point on the grid.

Answer (score 5):

calculate the `g1(x, y) - g2(x, y)` on a `mgrid[]` and then draw the line by `contour(..., levels=[0])`, here is an example. Since you did not post any sample data and code, I use sklearn to generate the sample data. You only need the code after `#plot code from here`:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import mixture

np.random.seed(0)
C1 = np.array([[3, -2.7], [1.5, 2.7]])
C2 = np.array([[1, 2.0], [-1.5, 1.7]])

X_train = np.r_[
    np.random.multivariate_normal((-5, -5), C1, size=100),
    np.random.multivariate_normal((5, 5), C2, size=100),
]

clf = mixture.GMM(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(X_train)

#define g1(x, y) and g2(x, y)

def g1(x, y):
    return clf.predict_proba(np.column_stack((x, y)))[:, 0]

def g2(x, y):
    return clf.predict_proba(np.column_stack((x, y)))[:, 1]

#plot code from here

X, Y = np.mgrid[-15:15:100j, -15:15:100j]
x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()

p = (g1(x, y) - g2(x, y)).reshape(X.shape)

pl.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1])
pl.contour(X, Y, p, levels=[0])
```

here is the output:

[image]