# Multi-class classification using discriminant function

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have a similar problem as described in the link below (multi class classification problem):

[Drawing decision boundary of two multivariate gaussian in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204320/drawing-decision-boundary-of-two-multivariate-gaussian-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, in my case, class 1 and 2 have different prior probabilities. How can I implement this in python?

I'm also confused with bivariate gaussian distribution. If it was  a univariate case, my discriminant function would be [something similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDDhj.png),
where P(Ci) is the prior probability.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Decision boundaries are contours (i.e., lines or surfaces of constant value) of the posterior class probability p(class | data). Use Bayes' rule to get p(class | data) from p(data | class) (that is, the Gaussian bump for each class) and p(class) (that is, prior probability for each class). My advice is to make a Python function to compute p(class | data) for one of the classes (just pick one or the other), then use a plotting function from Scipy or any plotting library to plot the contours. Practice first by plotting contours of any made-up functions, then work on your p(class | data).